# What is the term for for filling something with useless things?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for for filling something with useless things?  For example

> My head was ___ with useless information at school.
>   He ____ his baggage with useless stuff

Comment: What's wrong with "filled"?

Comment: I don't think there's any special word for this.

Comment: Did you take a look at a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fill) (click the verb tab on that page). There isn't a special verb for filling with useless things as opposed to filling with good things. But you could use less formal verbs, *crammed, stuffed, packed, choked,* which come with some overtone of disapproval.

Comment: "Stuffed" is probably most idiomatic, for this sense.  (But use a thesaurus, as suggested.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try ***littered***.

> My mind was ***littered*** (with useless information) at school.
>   He ***littered*** his
>   baggage (with useless stuff).

ODO:

> **[litter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/litter)**
>   *VERB*
>   **1.2** (usually *be littered with*) **Fill with examples of a particular thing**, **typically** something bad or **unpleasant**:
>
> ‘news pages have been littered with doom and gloom about company
>   collapses

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "cluttered" would work.

Comment: Hello, Robert. Your answer was flagged automatically as low-quality for its length. Please include some references and explanation that can support your answer. Note such a short answer could be downvoted and delete-voted. Good luck.